# Type error: 'GetServerSideProps' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof GetServerSideProps'?

Tags: typescript, next.js

## Index.tsx

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import Head  from "next/head"
import { sanityClient, urlFor  } from "../sanity"
import Link from 'next/link'
import {Collection, address} from '../typings';
import  GetServerSideProps  from 'next';

interface props {
  collections: Collection

}

const Home=({collections}: props) => {
  return (

    
  <div className='bg-yellow-400 max-auto  flex min-h-screen flex-col py-10 px-10 '>
      <Head>
        <title>Ordinal Cats</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fevicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      
        <h1 className='w-52 text-xl font-extralight sm:w-80 py-5'>
          <span className='font-extrabold underline decoration-orange-600/50'>Ordinal Cats</span>
        </h1>        
   

      <main className='bg-orange-500 rounded-lg p-10 shadow-xl shadow-black items-center ' >
        <div className='grid space-x-3 md:grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-1 2xl:grid-cols-4'>
          {collections?.map(collection => (

            
            <div key={collection.slug.current} className='flex flex-col items-center'>
              <img className='h-70 w-50 rounded-2xl object-cover' src={urlFor(collection.mainImage).url()} alt="" />
            <div>
            <h2 className='text-3xl items-center text-center'>{collection.title}</h2>
            <p className='mt-2 text-sm text-white text-center'>{collection.description}</p>
            <Link href={`${collection.slug.current}`} >
            <button className='cursor-pointer transition-all duration-200 hover:scale-105 h-16 bg-[#facf38] w-full text-Black rounded-full mt-2 font-bold disabled:bg-gray-400'>Mint</button>
            </Link>
            </div>
            </div>
            
          ))}
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>


  )
}

export default Home

export const  GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  const query = `*[_type == "collection"]{
    _id,
      title,
      address,
      description,
      nftCollectionName,
      mainImage{
      asset
      },
    previewImage {
      asset
    },
    slug {
      current
    },
    creator -> {
      _id,
      name,
      address,
      slug{
        current
      },
    },
  }`

  const collections = await sanityClient.fetch(query)

  return{
    props: {
      collections
    }
  }
  
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpb60.png)

My Backend File // typings.d.ts

```
interface Image{
    asset: {
        url: string
    }
}

export interface Creator {
    _id:string
    name:string
    address:string
    slug:{
        current:string
    }
    image:Image
    bio:string
}

export interface Collection {
    _id:string
    title:string
    description:string
    nftCollectionName:string
    address:string
    slug:{
        current:string
    }
    creator:Creator
    mainImage:Image
    previewImage:Image
}
```

My project is running successfully in local host without any error, but when im running comming 'npm run build' it is giving me bunch of errors , im trying to deploy it on vercel. but it is showing npm run build exited 1 . please help me out with this errors, i have tried to delete node modules and reinstalll the packages but it is not working.

Im expecting to deploy it on host. My code is working fine in my local host system. but when i am trying to deploy it , it is giving me errors. and it is not deploying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetServerSideProps` is the type of `getServerSideProps`

so you want to construct your function like

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  // ...
}
```

See typescript docs [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript#static-generation-and-server-side-rendering)

PS. this also threw me off the first time I used it, takes some getting use to.